# Boundness of an integral of a function

Tags: calculus

Let $f(z,y)$ a positive continuous function with respect to its arguments $z\in[0,1]$ and $y\in[0,\infty)$ and $\alpha >0$. If we have

$$
\lim_{y\rightarrow+\infty}\int\limits_0^1f(z,y)\,dz\leq \alpha
$$

Is it sufficient to conclude that $f(z,y)$ is bounded?

Comment: Take $f$ independent of $y$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

The answer is negative.

The idea is to build a map with unbounded narrow bumps (using [bump maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function?wprov=sfti1)) as $y \to \infty$. Narrow enough for the integral to be always bounded by $\alpha$.